# Java 8 lambda create list of Strings from list of custom class objects

Tags: java, string, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have the following qustion:

How can I convert the following code snipped to Java 8 lambda style?

```
List<String> tmpAdresses = new ArrayList<String>();
for (User user : users) {
    tmpAdresses.add(user.getAdress());
}
```

Have no idea and started with the following:

```
List<String> tmpAdresses = users.stream().map((User user) -> user.getAdress());
```

Comment: You're almost there. Assuming your map lambda returns a `String` just add `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to `map(...)`.

Comment: Note: `(User user) -> user.getAddress()` can be written as `user -> user.getAddress()` or just `User::getAddress`

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need to [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) your `Stream` into a `List`:

```java
List<String> adresses = users.stream()
    .map(User::getAdress)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For more information on the different `Collectors` visit the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

`User::getAdress` is just another form of writing `(User user) -> user.getAdress()` which could as well be written as `user -> user.getAdress()` (because the type `User` will be inferred by the compiler)

Answer (score 9):

It is extended your idea:

```
List<String> tmpAdresses = users.stream().map(user ->user.getAdress())
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: You should add a new answer if its better/ alternative than the other one. Explain how its better.

Answer (score 4):

One more way of using lambda collectors like above answers

```
 List<String> tmpAdresses= users
                  .stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.mapping(User::getAddress, Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there, you just need to collect streams in a List.

```
 List<String> addressList =
  users
    .stream()
    .map(user -> user.getAddress())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: How is *your* answer different to the already existing ones posted **5 years** ago?

Comment: I am new here, just want to contribute more and more. That's why I didn't check  the timing of previous answers.

Comment: You should check whether your answer is different from other answers, we don't want 50 answers to one question where all are saying the exact same thing. If you want to contribute I invite you to search for [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20is:q%20answers:0) (e.g. for the java tag) directly.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Lino.
Will surely search for unanswered questions, and try to give solutions.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this to convert `Long` to `String`:

```java
List<String> ids = allListIDs.stream()
                             .map(listid-> String.valueOf(listid))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the OPs question, though. OP is explicitly asking to map a `User` to its `adress`. Also how is your question different to the already existing ones?